# Accessing object fields by name in PL/pgSQL object

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to access the fields/properties of an Object by a name passed in via text variable in a PL/SQL fnction.  For instance, instead of:

```
obj.fieldA
```

I would like to do something like:

```
obj['fieldA']
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in PL/SQL?  I am using Postgres, so perhaps I should say PL/pgSQL, but I hope that common syntax exists.

Comment: Well you can't do that in Oracle PL/SQL so you might as well remove the tag. Maybe Postgres can do some magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I know, the compiled language PL/SQL doesn't allow it. Usually this is a feature of dynamic languages. PLpgSQL doesn't support this feature too, but there are few workarounds:

- dynamic SQL

  ```
  CREATE TABLE foo(a int, b varchar, c date);
  INSERT INTO foo VALUES(10, 'Hello', CURRENT_DATE);

  DO $$
  DECLARE 
    foo_rec foo%ROWTYPE;
    colname text DEFAULT 'b';
    value text;
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM foo INTO foo_rec;
    EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I::text', colname) INTO value USING foo_rec;
    RAISE NOTICE '% = %', colname, value;
  END;
  $$;
  ```
- Transformation to `JSON` and reading value from `JSON` value

  ```
  DO $$
  DECLARE 
    foo_rec foo%ROWTYPE;
    colname text DEFAULT 'b';
    j json;
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM foo INTO foo_rec;
    j := row_to_json(foo_rec);
    RAISE NOTICE '% = %', colname, j->>colname;
  END;
  $$;
  ```

Today using `JSON` is most comfortable way.